# Having XP VM use my host OSX ssh tunnel to connect to a remote site?

Tags: windows, ssh, mac-osx, virtual-machines, ssh-tunnel

I am using Mac OSX and have Windows XP running on VMWare Fusion.  I'm creating an ssh tunnel from OSX to a remote server, and then trying to have Windows XP use that tunnel (I actually use a program called Proxifier on XP to filter my XP MS SQL Server traffic through that tunnel)

Note that I can successfully create an ssh tunnel (on port **9333**) from the XP putty to the remote host, and have SQL Server Proxify through that tunnel and it all works correctly.

However when I try to set up the tunnel in OSX, and have Proxifier in XP point to the OSX tunnel instead of localhost, it doesn't seem to connect.  Here is the OSX command i'm using to create the tunnel:

```
ssh -i /my/key -p 9001 -D 9333 -g me@remotehostname
```

Then I set my XP proxifier to point to **macosxhostname:9333** (instead of the previous **localhost:9333** which worked corrently when using putty)

Any suggestions on what I may have missed? My XP firewall is turned off while setting this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `ssh -D portnum` listens only on the Mac's local loopback addresses, which means the resulting proxy is no reachable from anything other than the Mac itself (not even from a VM running on the Mac). You could tell ssh to listen on all of its IPs with `-D 0:9333`, or (depending on the VM's network setup) specify an IP on the virtual network between the Mac and the VM (meaning it would only be reachable from the Mac and the Windows VM).